# Node.js - check if module is installed without actually requiring it

Tags: node.js, module, require

I need to check whether "mocha" is installed, before running it. I came up with the following code:

```
try {
    var mocha = require("mocha");
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    console.error("Mocha is probably not found. Try running `npm install mocha`.");
    process.exit(e.code);
}
```

I dont like the idea to catch an exception. Is there a better way?

Comment: I've answered but now I've noticed the "globally" word. By "globally" do you mean a module installed with `-g` option in `npm`? I.e. `npm install -g mocha`? Edit: AFAIK `require` will not find modules installed with `-g` option.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You should use `require.resolve()` instead of `require()`. `require` will load the library if found, but `require.resolve()` will not, it will return the file name of the module.

See [the documentation for require.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve)

```
try {
    console.log(require.resolve("mocha"));
} catch(e) {
    console.error("Mocha is not found");
    process.exit(e.code);
}
```

require.resolve() does throw error if module is not found so you have to handle it.

Comment: `require.resolve` still throws a error - that is what I'm trying to avoid - catching an exception.

Comment: Accepting the answer since other solutions are not cleaner in any way.

Comment: yes, but will this also look for globally installed modules? I want to check if a module is installed locally.

Comment: @AlexMills A better way to do that is using [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) where global is false by default.

Answer (score 3):

`module.paths` stores array of search paths for `require`. Search paths are relative to the current module from where `require` is called. So:

```
var fs = require("fs");

// checks if module is available to load
var isModuleAvailableSync = function(moduleName)
{
    var ret = false; // return value, boolean
    var dirSeparator = require("path").sep

    // scan each module.paths. If there exists
    // node_modules/moduleName then
    // return true. Otherwise return false.
    module.paths.forEach(function(nodeModulesPath)
    {
        if(fs.existsSync(nodeModulesPath + dirSeparator + moduleName) === true)
        {
            ret = true;
            return false; // break forEach
        }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

And asynchronous version:

```
// asynchronous version, calls callback(true) on success
// or callback(false) on failure.
var isModuleAvailable = function(moduleName, callback)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var dirSeparator = require("path").sep

    module.paths.forEach(function(nodeModulesPath)
    {
        var path = nodeModulesPath + dirSeparator + moduleName;
        fs.exists(path, function(exists)
        {
            if(exists)
            {
                callback(true);
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;

                if(counter === module.paths.length)
                {
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
if( isModuleAvailableSync("mocha") === true )
{
    console.log("yay!");
}
```

Or:

```
isModuleAvailable("colors", function(exists)
{
    if(exists)
    {
        console.log("yay!");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("nay:(");
    }
});
```

Edit: Note:

- `module.paths` is not in the [API](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)
- Documentation [states](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) that you can add paths that will be scanned by `require` but I couldn't make it work (I'm on Windows XP).

Comment: @AndreyM, just curious to know what you didn't like about this solution and why you marked the accepted answer as one that uses a try/catch hack to determine if a module exists? Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming because module.paths is not in the API, you didn't go with this. I can see this not being future proof if Node gets changed in some manner, whereas the try/catch strategy, despite being ugly, would be more reliable.  Still, this is an awesome answer and solves this without try/catch! +1 :)