# How to load a module only if it exists in node/gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp, node-modules

I'm trying to correctly configure my Gulp setup, and I want to load `moduleA` if it exists, or `moduleB` instead, if `moduleA` doesn't exists.

Trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701/10580177) to check if a file exists, here is my code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const moduleA = './moduleA.js';
const moduleB = './moduleB.js';

const myModule = require( (fs.existsSync(moduleA)) ? moduleA : moduleB );
```

But it is not working, my tasks always get the code from './moduleB.js' even if './moduleA.js' exists and is readable.

How can I modify this code to make it work, and require the correct module given the conditions?

---

**Edit:** I've tried the following code

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const itexists = true;
const moduleA = './moduleA.js';
const moduleB = './moduleB.js';

const myModule = require( (itexists === true) ? moduleA : moduleB );
```

and it gives me values from `moduleA` (of course without checking its existence), so I can at least assume that the syntax is correct and that the problem lies with `fs.existsSync()`.

For what I have understood, [`fs.existsSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) is supposed to give `true` or `false` as output, but apparently it is not working like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - check if module is installed without actually requiring it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302618/node-js-check-if-module-is-installed-without-actually-requiring-it)

Comment: No, even with `try ... catch` it does not work as expected.

Comment: I believe `require` follows different rules than the `fs` module as far as the current working directory. Maybe try something like this `fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, moduleA))`, and see if it works for you?

Comment: Using the path method seems to do the job, I'll test this more extensively as soon as possible. Meanwhile, if you want to put this in a proper answer, I can upvote and accept it. Thank you!