# Null dependencies in RequireJS when ajax returns a 404

Tags: requirejs

Is there any way to have requireJS optionally (like maybe through a plugin) return null for a dependency that failed with a 404?

For example:

```
require(["allow404!myscript"], function(myscript){
    console.info(myscript);  // myscript should be null if myscript doesn't exist
});
```

Comment: I've added a solution for your exact problem in another similar question. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/27422370/80779  I don't know what is Stackoverflow's policy on duplicated answers, so I'm not copying to whole answer content to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [requireJS optional dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164610/requirejs-optional-dependency)

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse [paths config fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks) to achieve this:

```js
require(["myModuleOrNull"], function(myModuleOrNull) {
    console.log(myModuleOrNull);
});
```

in your `requirejs` config:

```js
paths: {
    'myModuleOrNull': [
        'unreliable-module-location',
        // If above fails (timeout, 404, etc.) use the one below
        'null-module'
    ]
}
```

and the `null-module.js`:

```js
define([], function() {
    return null;
});
```

---

...but why would you want to do that? Handling optional `null` where a module is expected will be nothing but pain. Is there some specific reason for doing this?

Comment: It's perhaps not the best design, but I'm experimenting.  I'm building a lightweight SPA framework and am trying to avoid having to configure missing views or view reuse.

Comment: ja, im doing the same thing